# How to solve Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, geolocation

I am trying to build an `Ionic` location tracking App with the Cordova BackgroundGeolocation Plugin:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-geolocation

Unfortunately I am facing the following error since I installed the plugin:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
     at index.js:717
     at Module../node_modules/@ionic-native/background-geolocation/index.js
 (index.js:975)
     at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:83)
     at Module../src/app/app.module.ts (app.component.ts:15)
     at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:83)
     at Module../src/main.ts (main.ts:1)
     at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:83)
     at Object.0 (main.ts:12)
     at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:83)
     at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45)
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { Toast } from '@ionic-native/toast/ngx';

import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TabsPage } from './tabs/tabs.page';

import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { AuthenticateService } from './authentication.service';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from '@angular/fire/auth';

import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation/ngx';
import { NativeGeocoder } from '@ionic-native/native-geocoder/ngx';
import { BackgroundGeolocation } from '@ionic-native/background-geolocation';


import * as firebase from 'firebase';
firebase.initializeApp(environment.firebase);

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
    AngularFireAuth,
    TabsPage,
    AuthenticateService,
    Toast,
    Geolocation,
    NativeGeocoder,
    BackgroundGeolocation
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "ionic3-barcodev4",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.21",
    "@angular/common": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "^8.2.14",
    "@ionic-native/background-geolocation": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/barcode-scanner": "^5.16.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^5.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/google-analytics": "^5.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/native-geocoder": "^5.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/network": "^5.16.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.16.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.16.0",
    "@ionic-native/toast": "^5.16.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^4.11.4",
    "@ionic/pro": "2.0.4",
    "@mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation": "^3.1.0",
    "angularfire2": "^5.2.1",
    "cordova-android": "7.1.4",
    "cordova-ios": "^5.1.1",
    "cordova-plugin-add-swift-support": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "4.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "2.0.5",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "4.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder": "^3.2.2",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-x-toast": "2.7.2",
    "core-js": "^2.6.10",
    "firebase": "^5.11.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "~0.12.3",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^7.2.4",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^7.2.4",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.3.21",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "^8.2.14",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^1.4.1",
    "@ionic/lab": "1.0.24",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "~10.12.0",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.6",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.12.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-x-toast": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {
        "GEOLOCATION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "To track your walks"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-network-information": {},
      "cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you get this error when you're building the app or at run-time?

Comment: At run-time in the console of the browser.

Comment: Can you update your question with the `package.json` dependencies. You might have the wrong versions installed of things.

Comment: Doesn't look like the geo plugin works with the version of Cordova that you're using. https://github.com/mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation/blob/67a605a413e9fa3bfad5a129a06afed943004901/package.json#L29

Comment: Here's the version support from the docs: https://github.com/mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation#compatibility

Comment: I think you should check the versions of your dependencies here and make sure you have the right versions of things installed that work together.

Comment: Do I have to have the exact same versions or is it also ok to have higher versions?

Comment: No one can tell you what versions to run. That's your source code and only you know what works with it. You'll have to figure that out somehow by experimenting or reading upgrade guides.

Comment: I just reinstalled cordova with the version mentioned on https://github.com/mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation#compatibility but unfortunately I am getting the same error...